# React Native - useContext not working with useState (setProviderId is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state, use-context

So I'm trying to pass on setProviderId through React Context but when I try to change it through setProviderId(pid) it returns an error stating that setProviderId is not a function, setProviderId is undefined:

> ERROR  TypeError: setProviderId is not a function. (In
> 'setProviderId(pid)', 'setProviderId' is undefined)

App.js:

```
export const ProviderContext = createContext(() => {});
export default function App() {
const [providerId, setProviderId] = useState(`0`);
  return (
     <ProviderContext.Provider value={setProviderId}>
         <ShowScreen />
     </ProviderContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

ShowScreen.js:

```
import ProviderContext from '../../../../App.js';

export const ShowScreen = () => {
    const setProviderId = useContext(ProviderContext);
    const pid = '1';
    return(
      <Button onPress={() => {
          setProviderId(pid);
        }} title="Press Me"/>
    );
}
```

Comment: `import ProviderContext from '../../../../App.js';` is importing the default which is your App component. Change it to a named import `import { ProviderContext } from '../../../../App.js';
`

Answer (score 2):

You are doing wrong pass of **value** `value={setProviderId}` it must be `{{setProviderId}}` , but related with this article [Caveats](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats) , will be good that you define in the component

```
const state = {
  setProviderId,
  providerId,
}
```

then pass it to provider like this `value={ state }`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments on my original question. I was using:

```
import ProviderContext from 'App.js';
```

which imported default app component so all I had to do was change it to:

```
import { ProviderContext } from 'App.js';
```